# Can you prove that function is continuous by using limits

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

So there is a type of problems that goes something like this :
Check continuity of a function

$f(x) = y$ when $x$ is from $\Bbb Q$

$f(x) = z$ when $x$ is from $\Bbb R\ / \ \Bbb Q$

Usually idea is to find one or few possible points in which function is continuous and then proceed with epsilon delta proof.
I was wondering if the left and right limits are equal to $f(x)$ regardless of does $x$ approaches $a$ with rational or irrational numbers, does that mean that function is continuous in $a$.
I know this is a valid proof when f(x) = $w$ for $x$ from $\Bbb R$

Comment: Are you asking if the function approaches something for irrational values then is it continuous (for real values)?

Comment: The goal is to find points in which function  is continious. If left limit is equal to right and both are equal to f(x) when x aprroaches a ,regardless of does x approaches a with rational or irrational numbers, does that mean that f is continuous in that point a.

Comment: I know that is the case generally. But in this case we will have four limts. Let's say we are checking for continuity in point 1. We have both left and right limit when x aprroaches 1 as a rational sequence and as a irrational sequence. That's because f(x) = y when x is from Q and f(x)=z when x is from R/Q. If all 4 of those limits are equal is f continuous at 1? I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough english isn't my native language

Comment: Can you tell us what $y$ and $z$ are? Are fixed real numbers or what?

Comment: For example let f(x) be sinx when x is from Q and f(x)= cos x when x is from R\Q

Comment: So what you are asking is if the left limit and right limit  of the rational sequence are equal and the left limit and right limit of the irrational sequence are equal is the function continuous ?

Comment: Yes. Is function continious in that specific point?

Comment: @Gregory, you have to write in your question that $y$ and $z$ are functions of $x$.

Comment: The technique of sequences is useful when proving discontinuity by choosing two different sequences leading to different limits. But using that technique for proving continuity requires you to take arbitrary sequence and prove that limit is same for any such sequence. Just taking four sequences will not help here.

Comment: @Angelo there is no edit button in left corner any more

Comment: The original poster had to write it in his question, not in a comment after that he downvoted me. Moreover he has not written anything about the functions $()$ and $()$. Are they continuous or not?

Comment: Yea this became a mess. I'll just make another question with specific example.

Comment: There is a function defined as follows for all real numbers. If $x$ is rational and is equal to $\frac pq$ as a fraction in lowest terms with $q$ positive, then define $f(x)=\frac 1q$ ($f(0)=1$). For $x$ irrational, define $f(x)=0$. Can you identify where this is continuous? Generally you have either special points to concentrate on, or a class of points of a particular kind (rational, or irrational) - in this second case you will normally want to choose a typical point of the kind under consideration - eg begin Let $x\in \mathbb Q$ ... - then your proof will serve for all rational numbers.

Comment: "idea is to find one or few possible points in which function is continuous": what ??

Comment: English isn't my native and this is like my second question here so I don't how to write in math symbols .I'll try one more time. Let f(x) be sin x if x is from Q and f(x)=cosx if x is from R\Q. I was wondering if sin p/4 = cos pi/4 and both left and right limit of both sequences are equal to sin pi/4 and cos pi/4 can I conclude from this that f is continuous at pi/4 without epsilon delta proof

Comment: @Gregory, I hope my second addendum in my answer is useful for you.

Comment: Angelo yes, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your function $\;f(x)\;$ is continuous on $\;\big]-\infty,+\infty\big[\;$ if and only if $\;y=z\;.$

If $\;y\ne z\;,\;$ there does not exist any point $\;x\in\mathbb{R}\;$ in which the function $\;f(x)\;$ is continuous.

If $\;y=z\;,\;$ the function $\;f(x)\;$ is continuous in all points $\;x\in\mathbb{R}\;.$

**Addendum 1**

In the case that $\;y\;$ and $\;z\;$ are not fixed real numbers but continuous functions of $\;x\;,\;$ then

$f(x)\;$ is continuous in the points $\;x\;$ such that $\;y(x)=z(x)\;.$

For example,

$f(x)=$
$\begin{cases}
\sin x\quad\text{ if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
\cos x\quad\text{ if }x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\
\end{cases}$

is continuous in all points $\;x=\dfrac{\pi}4+k\pi\;$ where $\;k\in\mathbb{Z}\;,$

in which $\;\sin x=\cos x\;.$

**Addendum 2**

If $\;y(x)\;$ and $\;z(x)\;$ are two functions (continuous or not) ,

if $\quad f(x)=$
$\begin{cases}
y(x)\quad\text{ for any }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
z(x)\quad\text{ for any }x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\
\end{cases}\quad,$

if $\;x^*\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

if , for all the sequences $\;\{x’_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\;$ and $\;\{x’’_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\;$ such that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x’_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x’’_n=x^*\in\mathbb{R}\;,\;$ it follows that

$\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y\left(x’_n\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}z\left(x’’_n\right)=$
$\begin{cases}y\left(x^*\right)\;\text{ if }x^*\in\mathbb{Q}\\z\left(x^*\right)\;\text{ if }x^*\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}\;,$

then

$f(x)\;$ is continuous in $\;x^*\;.$

Comment: No, the goal isn't to find whether or not f is continious, goal is to find points in which it is

Comment: This is not true , for example consider $f(x)=0$ for rationals and $f(x)=x$ for irrationals then the function is continuous at $0$.

Comment: I have found the points in which the function is continuous in the case that $y=z$. If $y\ne z$, there do not exist neither left limit nor right limit.

Comment: Why have you downvoted my answer? It does not contain mistakes.

Comment: @Angelo I did not downvote

Comment: @VivaanDaga, but $x$ is not a constant, while $y$ and $z$ appear to be constants.

Comment: @Angelo if they are  constants then this answer is correct . In of the comments the asker states that they are not .

Comment: The original poster had to write it in his question, not in a comment after that he downvoted me. Moreover he has not written anything about the functions $y(x)$ and $z(x)$. Are they continuous or not?

Comment: I didn't downvoted you I upvoted  you to make it 0

Comment: Who has downvoted me? And why?

Comment: Yea I know the answer . I was wondering if sin p/4 = cos pi/4 and both left and right  limit of both sequences are equal to sin pi/4 and cos pi/4 can I conclude from this that f is continuous at pi/4 without epsilon delta proof?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)=0$ at the irrationals and $f(x)=1$ at the rationals then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ equals to $1$ for both the left and right limit but $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ equals to $0$ for both the left and right limit .

Comment: But if f(x) is equal to 1 at both rationals and irrationals ?

Comment: @Gregory Then the function would just be the constant function 1

Comment: Dana would you mind checking my last comment in angelo original answer

Answer (score 0):

The criterion for continuity is

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a).$$

In the given example, the limit exists nowhere (unless $y=z$), so the case is closed.